# Insert new element to an XML file using SAX Filter

Tags: java, xml, filter, sax

I have an XMl file that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<game >
  <moves>
    <turn>2</turn>
    <piece nr="1" />
    <turn>4</turn>
    <piece nr="1" />

  </moves>
</game>
```

I am writing a Java program that takes the XML file as input then parses it with SAX and SAX filter and computes:

- the sum of the content of turn element (here=6)
- the number of piece elements (here=2)

Then I want to use a SAX filter in order to generate an output XML file that are the same as the input one but with an additional element like:

```
<s:statistics>
    <s:turn-total>6</s:turn-total>
    <s:piece-count>2</s:piece-count>
</s:statistics>
```

The prefix `s` is a reference to a [namespace](http://www.oniel.com/ns/test/).

My program so far is:

```
 public class test{     
         public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                if (args.length != 2) {
                System.err.println("error ");
                System.exit(1);
                }
                String xmlInput = args[0];
                String filteredXML = args[1];
                test test1 = new test();
                    test1.sax(xmlInput, filteredXML);
            }
    private void sax(String gameXML, String filteredGameXML)throws Exception{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( gameXML);
        InputSource is = new InputSource(fis);
        XMLReader xr = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        XMLFilter xf = new MyFilter();
        xf.setParent(xr);
        xr = xf;
        xr.parse(is);
        xr.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", true);
        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(handler);
    }
    private class MyFilter extends XMLFilterImpl{
             StringBuffer buffer;
         int temp=0;
             int sum=0;
             String ff;
             int numof=0;
             private MyFilter() {}

            @Override
                public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
                     System.out.println( "START DOCUMENT" );
                    numof=0;        
                }

                public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String  name,   Attributes attributes) throws SAXException{
                    if(localName.equals("turn")){
                        buffer=new StringBuffer();
                        }
                    if("piece".equals(name)){
                        numof++;
                    }
                }

                public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
                    String s=new String(ch, start, length);
                    if(buffer!=null){
                        buffer.append(s);
                        }
                }

                public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String name)throws SAXException {
                    if(buffer!=null ){
                        ff=buffer.toString();
                        temp=Integer.valueOf(ff);
                        sum=sum+temp;
                        }
                        buffer=null;
                }
                public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
                    System.out.println( "END DOCUMENT" );
                    System.out.println("sum of turn: "+ sum);
                    System.out.println("sum of piece: "+ numof);
                }
         }

    }
```

What should I do next?

Comment: And what is the problem? You have told us what you want to achieve and given us a code dump. Is the code not working? If not what are the errors you get. If it works but not as expected how does the output differ from your expectation? Please clarify your question.

Comment: i want to know how can i insert the new element "<s:statistics>" to the xml file?
and how can i generate the xml file as output?

Comment: With SAX Filter you can modify the parsed tree but you cannot output the modified xml file. For a better understanding please refer to this: http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch08.html Probably the best way to go is to use DocumentBuilder - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html or SAXBuilder - http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/input/SAXBuilder.html to add the element after you have created it. Hope it helped

Comment: There is a problem with how you convert characters to a string--it will probably not bite you with this input, but just for the understanding: The parser is free to hand you the character content in  arbitrary chunks. Since there might be non us ascii characters in the content, i.e. more than one byte, you cannot convert the byte array to a string until you completely got it, in the enedElement() method.

Comment: @forty-two: Its actually a char array, so there won't be any charset problems, but you are right that the the new String is unnecessary. StringBuffer has a method to directly append parts of a char array.

Comment: @Jörn Horstmann: Of course it is! Stupid me!

Answer (score 4):

Your `XMLFilter` should delegate to another `ContentHandler` that serializes the document based on the sax events.

```
SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory)TransformerFactory.newInstance();
TransformerHandler serializer = factory.newTransformerHandler();
Result result = new StreamResult(...);
serializer.setResult(result);

XMLFilterImpl filter = new MyFilter();
filter.setContentHandler(serializer);

XMLReader xmlreader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
xmlreader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces", true);
xmlreader.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes", true);
xmlreader.setContentHandler(filter);

xmlreader.parse(new InputSource(...));
```

Your callback should delegate to the `super` implementation, which forwards the events to the serializing `ContentHandler`.

```
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    super.startElement(namespaceURI, localName, qName, atts);
    ...
}
```

In your `endElement` callback you can check if your are at the final closing tag and add additional sax events.

```
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    super.endElement(namespaceURI, localName, qName);
    if ("game".equals(localName)) {
        super.startElement("", "statistics", "statistics", new AttributesImpl());
        char[] chars = String.valueOf(num).toCharArray();
        super.characters(chars, 0, chars.length);
        super.endElement("", "statistics", "statistics");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1:  This is the right tactic.  The OP wanted a namespace for the new element, but that should be relatively easy to add.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong but i think XMLReader and XMLFilter are not really supposed to change a document. I can provide a different approach which with you can change the content of your document too:

```
public class ExtXMLConfig {
private JAXBContext context;
private Marshaller m;
private Unmarshaller um;
private Schema schema = null;

/**
 * Creates an ExtXMLConfig-object, which uses rootClass as object to parse
 * and save XML-files.
 * 
 * @param rootClass
 *            the class use create/parse xml-files from
 * @throws JAXBException
 */
public ExtXMLConfig(Class<?> rootClass) throws JAXBException {
    context = JAXBContext.newInstance(rootClass);

    init();
}

/**
 * Creates an ExtXMLConfig, which uses a classPath like javax.xml.bin to use
 * all classes in that path to parse and write xml-files
 * 
 * @param classPath
 *            the class path containing all needed java-objects
 * @throws JAXBException
 */
public ExtXMLConfig(String classPath) throws JAXBException {
    context = JAXBContext.newInstance(classPath);

    init();
}

/**
 * Parses a xml-file into a JavaObject.
 * 
 * @param file
 *            path to the xml-file
 * @return a java-Object
 */
public Object load(String file) {
    return load(new File(file));
}

/**
 * Parses a xml-file into a JavaObject.
 * 
 * @param xml
 *            File-object representing the xml-file
 * @return a java-Object
 */
public Object load(File xml) {
    um.setSchema(schema);

    if (xml.exists() && xml.isFile()) {
        try {
            return um.unmarshal(xml);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to open file: " + xml.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Saves a object into a xml-file.
 * 
 * @param xml
 *            the object to save
 * @param file
 *            path to the file to save to
 */
public void save(Object xml, String file) {
    save(xml, new File(file));
}

/**
 * Saves a object into a xml-file.
 * 
 * @param xml
 *            the object to save
 * @param file
 *            File-object representing the file to save to
 */
public void save(Object xml, File file) {
    if (xml != null) {
        m.setSchema(schema);

        if (!file.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                m.marshal(xml, file);
            } catch (JAXBException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Returns a formatted string representation of a xml-file given as a
 * java-Object.
 * 
 * @param xml
 *            the java-object to parse the xml from.
 * @return a formatted string representation of the given object
 */
public String toString(Object xml) {
    StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
    try {
        m.setSchema(schema);
        m.marshal(xml, out);

        return out.toString();
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private void init() throws JAXBException {
    m = context.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");

    um = context.createUnmarshaller();
}
```

Using this class to parse your xml-Files you would only need a Class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement // used to parse this class as xml-Root
public class Game {
   private Move moves;

   public Game() {};

   public void setMove(Move moves) {
      this.moves = moves;
   }

   public Moves getMoves() {
      return this.moves;
   }
}
```

with Move being an instance of another class which has the fields you need and also has a annotation for XmlRootElement.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the replay, it works but unfortunately i have to do that using Sax Filters(using Sax Fliter u can modify ur xml file )

Answer (score 0):

Using @Jorn Horstmann's (http://stackoverflow.com/users/139595/jorn-horstmann) answer from above you can easily add the missing elements. But to write the results to an XML file you should use the TransformerHandler.

Just create a very basic ContentHandler and use it instead of the DefaultHandler. In the ContentHandler you can implement all the basic functions (startDocument, startElement etc.) and add every element to a new Transformer.
e.g.
In your startDocument function:

```
Transformer t = hd.getTransformer();
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
hd.startDocument();
```

And then (in each other function) add this:
e.g. for startElement:

```
hd.startElement(uri,localName,name,attributes);
```

Finally you can write all this to a file in the endDocument method.