# Can we modify the XML file, like deleting,updating the nodes using SAX parser at run-time?

Tags: java

I am new to xml parsing, can we update or modify like deleting the node of the XML using SAX parser at run-time, and stream the updated data as XML, or transform it to our own format if we require? As the DOM parser does.

```
dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            docBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = docBuilder.parse("src/"+xmlFile);

             tranformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
             transformer = tranformerFactory.newTransformer();

             for (int i = 0; i < inputElementsArrayToRemove.length; i++) 
             {
                 element = (Element)document.getElementsByTagName(inputElementsArrayToRemove[i]).item(0);

                 if(element != null)
                 {
                    // Removes the node from the document
                     element.getParentNode().removeChild(element);
                 }
             }

             // Normalize the DOM tree to combine all adjacent nodes
            document.normalize();

            // Here, transforming(Converting) the document source to the another XML file
            Source source = new DOMSource(document);
            Result dest = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(new File("src/"+resultXmlFileName)));

            // transform method to write out the DOM as XML data.
            transformer.transform(source, dest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the [XMLReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html) and [XMLFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLFilter.html) APIs. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10598035/139595) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10599507/139595) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

We can Read or Write xml using SAX parser. to edit or update we need to use DOM parser only.

Answer (score 0):

You can not.  SAX Parser produces stream of events and feeds them to your handler.
Handler doessomething it likes with it.

DOM parser produces node tree, and you can modify it and  save it back as XML
( but it also consumes memory )

XPP parser allows you to pull xml events out of stream one by one,  and you can 
wrap it with your parser and modify events on the fly.  I would speculate is comes closes 
to your task

Answer (score 0):

Nope. SAX is event based parser which tells as when it encounter tokens. It is used for reading. Can we write using it?