# Reading and Updating XML string

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have text file with more than one XML documents in it. How can I parse this xml and update few of the element values.
There could be possibility when I have repeated element names in a single xml or multiple xmls in the same text file.In that case I would be referring to parent element value.
I looked into Java XPath API but it needs single XML document to parse. Here I have multiple xmls in a single file as a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split them with `"<?xml"` or by the starting tag of each enclosed document so that you will have a set of well structured xml documents.

Then, you can create a chain of outputstreams and use technique to update the needed elements with SAX described in

[Can we modify the XML file, like deleting,updating the nodes using SAX parser at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716533/can-we-modify-the-xml-file-like-deleting-updating-the-nodes-using-sax-parser-at)

[Insert new element to an XML file using SAX Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598035/insert-new-element-to-an-xml-file-using-sax-filter)

Answer (score 0):

A valid XML document must have a root element under which you can specify all other elements. It is a document where only ONE root element can be present. Read here , [XML Specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-document) point 2.1 .

So , first try to convert the file into a valid XML document and then parse it using regular APIs. You have to read the entire file into a stream , prefix and suffix it with some `<root>` element and present that stream to a XML Parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple XML documents in one file you could either split the file into one XML document per file and parse each file separately. Or you can add a root node on your own to create a valid XML document.